# Jquery script works in all browsers except IE8 and lower

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am running an ecommerce shop and the following script is used to add an item to the cart without a page reload.  It works in all major browsers including IE9 but it just does the default page reload with IE8 and below.  No errors show but it reloads the page which it IS NOT supposed to do.  Here is the code-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cart_quantity').live('submit', function() {
        $('#button_submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        var options = {};

        options = { to: "#ajax_cart", className: 'ui-effects-transfer' };

        $("#button_add_cart").effect('transfer',options,1300);

        var datas_form = $('#cart_quantity').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax_add_cart.php',
            data: datas_form,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                var datas = data.split("|");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#content_products').html(datas[0]);
                    $('#content_total').html(datas[1]);
                    $('#fila_' + datas[2]).fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
                    $('#content_total').fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
                }, 1300);
            }
        });
        $('#button_submit').attr('disabled', '');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 1):

Two tips:

1. add `e.preventDefault()` *to the beginning of the handler*. Any error in the handler will result in `return false` not executing and the browser performing the default action unless `preventDefault` was called *before* the error.
2. avoid live submit handlers, they are simulated in old IE via the click handler (as submit events do not bubble), which can lead to various perks (see e.g. [bug 7061](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7061)).

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! Point 2 from Tgr especially because it turned me in the right direction. Here is what fixed it- $('#cart_quantity').submit(function() { instead of the .live('submit' that I had previously been trying. It now works in IE 7-9 and of course in the other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an `event.preventDefault()` to the submit function

source: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Ok, I tried the event.preventDefault() but it still did the same thing. It's like the browser just ignores the transfer effect and the script all together and just does the default behavior. No errors are thrown in the IE developers tool either. It's just strange because I use jquery all over the site and it always works with the different browsers. Any ideas why IE 8 and below just ignore this script?